# Show that detF(X,t) is positive in continuum mechanics?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, continuum-mechanics

I want to show that the determinant of the field $detF$ at the point $X \in B$ is positive, when the following motion.

I think that time derivative of Jacobin is positive for $t > 0$.
However, I cannot see how this helps.

**How to start to show that the $det F(X, t) > 0$?**

I think the answer of the other question in the exercise can be found by $X = \phi(x,t) = F(t)^{-1} x$ so probably the components are $F^{-1}_{1} = t/X_{1} -1$, $F_{2}^{-1} = (t - X_{2}) / X_{3}$, and $F_{3}^{-1} = (X_{3} - t) / X_{2}$.

I used the normal inverse formula to count those things. **Is there any sense in those inverse components?**

**Exericise 4.29 from Gonzalez in Continuum Mechanics:**

[image]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have $x= F(t) X$, so the matrix $F(t)$ is obvious, and the calculus of $det F(t)$ is very simple, it is always stricly positive, so $F(t)$ is (easily) invertible, and you have $X= (F(t))^{-1} x$.

Comment: Is the matrix F(t) then ( (1+T) 0 0, 0 1 t, 0 -t 0). It is easy to count this matrix determinant.

Comment: No, the last line of $F$ is $0 (-t) 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a motion function $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\chi}( \mathbf{X} ,t)$, the deformation gradient is given by

$$
\mathbf{F} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{\chi}(\mathbf X,t)}{\partial \mathbf X}
$$

If you carry this out, you should find that $det(\mathbf F) = (1+t)(1+t^2) > 0  \quad\forall t>0$

As for finding the inverse motion function, you have to do a bit of algebra. You're given $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\chi}(\mathbf{X},t)$, the components of which form 3 linearly independent equations which you must use to solve for $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{\chi}^{-1}(\mathbf{x},t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I got the inverse components as $F_1^{-1} = t/x_{1} - 1$, $F_2^{-1} = (t - x_{2}) / x_{3}$, and $F_3^{-1} = (x_3 - t) / x_2$.